# Mapa abre antes de pegar a posição do GPS

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

Estou estudando programação para Andriod e me deparei uma característica que simplesmente não conheço nada, que é **a ordem de execução as funções**!   por favor , alguém poderia de dar uma luz?

**Explico, no meu exemplo eu chamo a** 
 - API para comunicar com o GPS, *(linha 90)*
 - DEPOIS para efetivamente pegar a posição (latitude e longitude) *(linha 103)* 
 - e então chamo **o mapa** ! *(linha 210)*

Mas não sei por que razão, **ele abre o mapa** ANTES de pegar a posição do GPS, ou seja, o mapa não tem posição pra abrir e da erro.

> Como sou novata, não sei exatamente se fui clara... Espero que vocês
>   me ajudem  a entender e a explicar. Cheguei ate aqui depois de muita
>   pesquisa, mas empaquei, pois não sei como abrir o mapa DEPOIS da
>   consulta da posição...

**Eis o código quer estou trabalhando**!

```
package jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

//import java.util.concurrent.atomic.DoubleAccumulator;

import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration;
import jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki.model.Report;

import static jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki.config.Constants.MAP_ZOOM;


/**
 * Created by ootaegd on 2016/12/16.
 */

public class PostPositionActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

    private GoogleMap map;
    private Marker marker = null;
    private LatLng locationLatLng;
    //private static final LatLng MATSUE = new LatLng(35.47222, 133.05056); //マーカ初期値
    //private LatLng locationLatLng = instantPosition;
    private float accuracy;
    //private static final LatLng instantPosition = new LatLng(35.3852243, 132.7339911);  //              izumo
    //private static final LatLng instantPosition = new LatLng(35.47222, 133.05056);      //マーカ初期値  matsue
    private String uuId;
    //private LatLng instantPosition;
    protected Realm realm;
    private TextView tvCoordinate;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_position);

        //前のactivityから渡されたデータを取得する
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        uuId = intent.getStringExtra("uuId");

        //realm設定
        Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);

        //toolbarを設定
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.post_position_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.headPositionTitle));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        onBtnGpsClicked();
        nextViewActivity();

        //Fragment を取得
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        tvCoordinate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_coordinate);
        callConnection();
    }

    /**
     * Getting the Google GPS API OnLine.
     *(linha 90)
     */
    private synchronized void callConnection() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.e("--------MESSAGE--------"," API loaded 01");
    }

    /**
     * Getting the actual GPS position.
      *(linha 103)
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location l = LocationServices
                .FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if(l != null){
            //tvCoordinate.setText(l.getLatitude()+" -- "+l.getLongitude()+"-----"+ l.getAccuracy());
            tvCoordinate.setText("Accuracy = "+ l.getAccuracy());
            accuracy = l.getAccuracy();
            Log.e("--------LOG--------", "latitude:  " + l.getLatitude());
            Log.e("--------LOG--------", "longitude: " + l.getLongitude());
            Log.e("--------LOG--------", "accuracy:  " + accuracy);
            // tvCoordinate.setText(" ||| "+l.getLatitude()+" ||| "+l.getLongitude()+" ||| ");
            // final LatLng instantPosition = new LatLng(35.3852243, 132.7339911); //izumo
            // final LatLng instantPosition = new LatLng(35.47222, 133.05056); // matsue
            locationLatLng = new LatLng(l.getLatitude(), l.getLongitude());
            //instantPosition = new LatLng(l.getLatitude(), l.getLongitude());
            Log.e("--------MESSAGE--------"," GPS get ok 02");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    /**
     * 次の画面へ遷移する処理
     */
    private void nextViewActivity() {
        //位置情報ボタンを押された時の処理
        Button btnPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPost);
        btnPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //位置情報を追加する
                addReport();

                // 画面を起動
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClassName("jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki", "jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki.PostConfirmationActivity");
                intent.putExtra("uuId",uuId);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * 現在地取得ボタンを押された時、現在地を取得する
     */
    private void onBtnGpsClicked() {
        Button btnPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);
        btnPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //現在地取得
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * GoogleMapを読み込む前に、オーバライドして処理を行う
     *
     * @param googleMap
     *(linha 210)
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady( GoogleMap googleMap ) {
        map = googleMap;

        Log.e("--------MESSAGE--------"," original get 03");
        // final LatLng instantPosition = new LatLng(35.3852243, 132.7339911); // izumo
        // final LatLng instantPosition = new LatLng(35.47222,   133.05056);   // matsue
        //locationLatLng = new LatLng(35.47222,   133.05056);   // matsue  //test
        setMarker(locationLatLng);

        // GoogleMapが押下された時の処理
        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick( LatLng latLng ){
                // クリックされるたびにマーカが増えていく
                // 一つ前のマーカは削除する
                marker.remove();
                //Mapが押下されたらその位置にピンを立てる
                //緯度経度を取得
                locationLatLng = latLng;
                //ピンを立てる
                setMarker(locationLatLng);
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Markerを立てる関数
     *
     * @param lacation　緯度経度情報
     */
    private void setMarker(LatLng lacation){
        marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(lacation)
                .title("報告場所")
                .draggable(false));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lacation, MAP_ZOOM));
    }

    /**
     * 位置情報を追加する
     * @return プライマリキー
     */
    private void addReport(){

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        //トランザクション開始
        realm.beginTransaction();

        //uuIdでターゲットを抽出
        Report report = realm.where(Report.class).equalTo("key",uuId).findFirst();
        //保存を行う
        report.setLat(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(locationLatLng.latitude)));
        report.setLon(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(locationLatLng.longitude)));
        report.setAccuracy(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(accuracy)));
        Log.e("--------MESSAGE--------", " Longitude 04 " + String.valueOf(report.getLon()));
        Log.e("--------MESSAGE--------", " Latitude 04 "  + String.valueOf(report.getLat()));
        Log.e("--------MESSAGE--------", " Accuracy 04 "  + String.valueOf(report.getAccuracy()));

        //トランザクション終了
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Coloca as linhas 90,103 e 210 destacadas.

Comment: @Taisbevalle, marquei as linhas, de inicio de cada funcao! por favor me diga se ficou melhor!

Comment: Sabe.. to achando que isso de "auto-didata" em java não vai rolar..... o bicho eh chucru.  Acho que vou ter que pagar pra aprender.

Comment: Assim fica melhor =)..Quando tiver alguma dúvida veja esse [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/51124)

Comment: eu ja li este manual.. :(   ele ma da muita dor.... vou ler de novo... :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ordem da execução dos métodos é a ordem em que são chamados e não a ordem em que são declarados.

A ordem como está a fazer é **pedir para ser criado** o mapa e depois **pedir para ser criado** o serviço de localização:

```
...
//Cria o mapa
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

...
//Cria o serviço de localização
callConnection();
```

Eu utilizei **pedir para ser criado**, em vez de apenas **criar**, porque ambos os métodos retornam antes do mapa e do serviço serem criados, a criação é processada de forma assíncrona.

O facto dos métodos serem chamados naquela ordem não garante que o resultado de cada um dos processamentos termine na mesma ordem.

Normalmente os processamentos assíncronos recorrem a *callbacks* para informar o código chamador do resultado do processamento.

O método [getMapAsync()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)), de *MapFragment*, usa uma implementação da interface [OnMapReadyCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback), passada como argumento.

O método [connect()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient#connect()) usa implementações de [GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) e [GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks), informadas ao construir o objecto [GoogleApiClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient).

Como não se sabe qual dos *callbacks* vai ser chamado primeiro, se `onConnected()` ou `onMapReady()`, é necessário (tentar)colocar o *marker* no mapa em ambos os métodos.

No método `onConnected()`:

```
if(map != null){
    setMarker(locationLatLng);
}
```

No método `onMapReady()`:

```
if(locationLatLng != null){
    setMarker(locationLatLng);
}
```

Comment: OBRIGADAAAAAA! nem sei como agradecer! Beijos a Portugal!